# Long type, left shift and right shift operations

Tags: c#, .net, bitwise-operators

Continuing my previous question
[Why I cannot derive from long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782927/why-i-cannot-derive-from-long)

I found an interesting problem.

Step one:

```
4294967296 & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000
```

Result: 4294967296.

Step two.

```
4294967296 & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF
```

Result: 0

Aha, So here I assume that 4294967296 == 0xFFFFFFFF

Let's check

```
(long)0x00000000FFFFFFFF
```

Result: 4294967295. Fail.

Let's double check

```
4294967296 >> 32
```

Result: 1. Fail.

The only explanation is that because i am using long where
some bit is reserved for sign. In C I would use unsigned long.
What do you think guys?

Comment: A number that looks like ...6 in decimal cannot possibly equal a number that looks like ...F in hex. One is even and one is odd!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
4294967296 & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 = 4294967296
```

This indicates that the value 4294967296 has no bits set in the lower 32-bits. In fact, 4294967296 is 0x100000000, so this is true.

```
4294967296 >> 32 = 1
```

Again, consistent.

In other words, your conclusion that 4294967296 is 0xFFFFFFFF is wrong so the remaining checks will not support this.

Comment: Shame on me. Thanks. But I came to this conclusion 
debugging the following code which does not work

                    long a = 2;
                    long b = 3;
                    long packed = a + b << 32;
                    
// now let's unpack
                    long a1 = packed & 0xFFFFFFFF;
                    long b1 = packed >> 32;

Result:
a1 = 0;
b1 = 5;

Where is an error? Must be some really simple mistake.

Comment: Your problem is operator precidence. Plus is processed before bit shifts. Try "long packed = a + (b << 32);"

Comment: precidence = precedence, silly typo. Figured I'd correct cause you may want to google for it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Um... I'm not sure why you came to the conclusions you did but 4294967296 is 0x100000000. To write out the bitwise AND's in easily readable hex...

```
0x0000000100000000 &
0x00000000FFFFFFFF =
0x0000000000000000

0x0000000100000000 &
0xFFFFFFFF00000000 =
0x0000000100000000
```

Both of those make perfect sense. Perhaps you're misunderstanding a bitwise AND... it maps the bits that are the same in both. Your comments seem more appropriate to a bitwise XOR than a bitwise AND (Which is not the operation you're using)...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are failing to understand the bitwise `and` operation.  The bitwise `and` will return the bits that are set in both.  If the two were the same then

```
(4294967296 & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) == 4294967296
```

and

```
(4294967296 & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) == 0xFFFFFFFF00000000
```

would both hold, but they obviously don't.